# Extending SilverStripe modules extension

Tags: silverstripe

I have installed a particular module in my SilverStripe installation. The following is the directory structure

```
- Root
  - framework
  - cms
  - mymodule
    - code
      - extensions
        - CustomClass.php
```

Here is an example of `CustomClass.php`

```
class CustomClass extends Extension {
    public function init() {
    }

    public function customMethod() {
    }
}
```

I need to override the `customMethod` method of the `CustomClass` class. I could easily change this method, but changing here will cause trouble in the future if the modules get updated. All the changes made will be lost.

So for this I want to extend the extension class used in modules.

I have created an extension `/mysite/extensions/MyCustomClass.php`

```
class MyCustomClass extends Extension {
    public function customMethod() {
       //do my code here
    }
}
```

but I have no idea how to apply this. I thought `CustomClass::add_extension("MyCustomClass ")` but surely this will not work because `add_extension` method doesn't exist in `CustomClass`.

How do we cope with this scenario? Can I use Injector instead? If yes, how can it be called in `mysite/_config.php` instead of `_config.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using injector does solve the problem but have to use `_config.yml` as well. Here is what I did.

File `/mysite/extensions/MyCustomClass.php`

```
class MyCustomClass extends CustomClass {
    public function customMethod() {
       //do my code here
    }
}
```

in `/mysite/_config/config.yml` I added following lines

```
Injector:
  CustomClass:
    class: MyCustomClass
```

And in `/mysite/_config.php` I added following line

```
$object = Injector::inst()->create('CustomClass');
```

And it all worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to achieve similar functionality without straight up replacing a previous extension. With SilverStripe's extension system, we can control not only what configuration settings are loaded [but the order they are loaded](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/#before-after-priorities). This is important to note because the `customMethod` function from an extension, it uses the first one it finds from all the extensions loaded.

Because of this, it can be only a matter of controlling when your `MyCustomClass` extension is loaded so you can have your own `customMethod` function run.

Let's say the "MyModule" module has the following YAML file defined:

```
---
Name: MyModuleExtensions
After:
  - 'framework/*'
  - 'cms/*'
---

Page:
  extensions:
    - CustomClass
```

All we need to do is specify a separate YAML file to run before this "MyModule" one. This can be accomplished like:

```
---
Name: MyCustomModule
Before:
  - MyModule/#MyModuleExtensions
---

Page:
  extensions:
    - MyCustomClass
```

Now, when you call your `customMethod` function on whatever class you have your extensions on (so in my example, the `Page` class), it will call the one from your `MyCustomClass` extension.